# How to execute dynamic query with sql""select c from T""".as[T] interpolation in slick

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to implement a function with Slick3 to return a tuple.

```
def executeQueryConfig2[T](sql: String, f : Option[T] => Unit): Future[T] = {
val action2 = sql"""$sql""".as[T].headOption
getDatabase(config).run(action2).mapTo[T].map(f(_)).recover{ case e: SQLException => println(e.getMessage) }
.......
}
```

The compiler shows the error:

```
Error:(66, 35) could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[T]
val action2 = sql"""$sql""".as[T].headOption
                              ^
```

If T is the type in types which have been implemented by the slick 3, how I implement such function?

Example:

```
executeQueryConfig2[Int]("SELECT C FROM T", f1(_))
```

Thanks.

Comment: See documentation (http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/sql.html#result-sets): `implicit val getMyResult = GetResult(r => MyCaseClass(r.<<, …))`

Comment: Sure. I have read the doc you mentioned. But I do not know exactly how to do it? Would you please show me some example code?

Comment: It is not possible to do this for the type parameter T; it needs to be done for the actual type(s) you're using. What do you mean with "If T is the type in types which have been implemented by the slick 3"?

Comment: Hi devkat, thanks for your response.

object GetResult {
  implicit object GetBigDecimal
  implicit object GetBoolean
  implicit object GetByte
  .........

These types have implemented implicitly by Slick.    Do we have some way to restrict  that T is one of these types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the `GetResult` function for your type `T`:

```scala
def executeQueryConfig2[T:ClassTag](sql: String, f: Option[T] => Unit)
    (implicit rconv: GetResult[T]): Future[T] = {
  val action2 = sql"""$sql""".as[T].headOption
```

By the way, the following statement doesn't compile since you can't invoke `f` on `T`, only on `Option[T]`.

```scala
  db.run(action2).mapTo[T].map(f(_)).recover{ case e: SQLException => println(e.getMessage) }
}
```